# Conversion Implicit in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following problem.

When I run the query in DataBase1..

```
declare @x float
select @x = Descripcion from Automotor.Modelo
where id = 57
select @x
```

the result is "1,7E+27"

But I run the query in DataBase2..

The result is 
"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to float."

The structure is the same have idea why this happens?

Comment: you declare `@x` to be a float, then try to stuff in some data from a varchar field... what do you expect should happen? Did you look at the structure of the table in DataBase2? it's obviously a varchar...

Comment: The structures are the same, the question is because a database 1 makes an implicit conversion and database 2 is not.

Comment: its a db configuration isn't it?

Comment: What is the language of the login in both cases? Maybe that comma as decimal separator is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The table in one database could have character data that isn't in the other, and the assignment (or at least validating the assignment operation) is trying to happen before the filter. This could even happen with the same data but different indexes, different statistics or a different query plan for other reasons, which could mean that SQL Server sees the data in a different order and comes across the bad value. But I would guess that even though the structures are identical, the data is not.

My suggestions are either:

(a) store your float data in a float column instead of a varchar column (preferable)

(b) short circuit the assignment problem like this:

```
SELECT @x = CASE WHEN Descripcion NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN Descripcion END
  FROM Automator.Modelo WHERE id = 57;
```